# Is it possible to use text swatches as multiselect on category pages? (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, attributes, layered-navigation, swatches, multiselect-attribute

The webshop has a attribute called **weight**. On the product page of a configurable product, the customer can choose the attribute value of this attribute. To show these attribute values as little tiles, I made a text swatch attribute, so they show up like this:
[image]

That's exactly what I wanted for the product page. But now, the filter on the category page of the attribute **weight** lost it's multiselect functionality. We use Mageplaza's Layered Navigation so the customer can select multiple attribute values to filter the products. If I switch the attribute from a text swatch to a dropdown, the filters on the category page are multiselect, but the filters on the product page are a dropdown (which is impossible to style like the little tiles).

Is there a way to get the best of both worlds? Show the product tiles on the product page, but the multiselect on the category page.